# I want to create four virtual machines with one CPU each and then bind the 4 virtual machines to four cloudlets

Tags: java

I using Cloudsim and trying to create 4 VM with 4 cloudlets and bind each VM to the four cloudlet but Im having errors, I tried to search online about the MIPS error, however I couldnt come up with anything. Hopefully I can get some help here

public class CloudSimExample11 {

```
    /**
     * The cloudlet list.
     */
    private static List<Cloudlet> cloudletList;
    /**
     * The vmlist.
     */
    private static List<Vm> vmlist;

    /**
     * Creates main() to run this example.
     *
     * @param args the args
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Log.printLine("Starting CloudSimExample1...");

        try {
            // First step: Initialize the CloudSim package. It should be called before creating any entities.
            int num_user = 1; // number of cloud users
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // Calendar whose fields have been initialized with the current date and time.
            boolean trace_flag = false; // trace events

            CloudSim.init(num_user, calendar, trace_flag);

            // Second step: Create Datacenters
            // Datacenters are the resource providers in CloudSim. We need at
            // list one of them to run a CloudSim simulation
            Datacenter datacenter0 = createDatacenter("Datacenter_0");

            // Third step: Create Broker
            DatacenterBroker broker = createBroker();
            int brokerId = broker.getId();

            // Fourth step: Create one virtual machine
            vmlist = new ArrayList<Vm>();

            // VM description
            int vmid1 = 1, vmid2 = 2, vmid3 = 3, vmid4 = 4;
            int mips = 500;
            long size = 10000; // image size (MB)
            int ram = 512; // vm memory (MB)
            long bw = 1000;
            int pesNumber = 1; // number of cpus
            String vmm = "Xen"; // VMM name

            // create VM
            Vm vm1 = new Vm(vmid1, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());

            Vm vm2 = new Vm(vmid2, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());
            
            Vm vm3 = new Vm(vmid4, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());

            Vm vm4 = new Vm(vmid4, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerSpaceShared());
           

            // add the VM to the vmList
            vmlist.add(vm1);
            vmlist.add(vm2);
            vmlist.add(vm3);
            vmlist.add(vm4);

            // submit vm list to the broker
            broker.submitVmList(vmlist);

            // Fifth step: Create one Cloudlet
            cloudletList = new ArrayList<Cloudlet>();

            // Cloudlet properties
            int id = 0;
            long length = 400000;
            long fileSize = 300;
            long outputSize = 300;
            UtilizationModel utilizationModel = new UtilizationModelFull();

            Cloudlet cloudlet1 = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
            cloudlet1.setUserId(brokerId);
            cloudlet1.setVmId(vmid1);
            id++;
            Cloudlet cloudlet2 = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
            cloudlet2.setUserId(brokerId);
            cloudlet2.setVmId(vmid1);
            id++;
            Cloudlet cloudlet3 = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
            cloudlet3.setUserId(brokerId);
            cloudlet3.setVmId(vmid3);
            id++;
            Cloudlet cloudlet4 = new Cloudlet(id, length, pesNumber, fileSize, outputSize, utilizationModel, utilizationModel, utilizationModel);
            cloudlet4.setUserId(brokerId);
            cloudlet4.setVmId(vmid4);
            // add the cloudlet to the list
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet1);
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet2);
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet3);
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet4);

// add the cloudlet to the list
            cloudletList.add(cloudlet1);

            // submit cloudlet list to the broker
            broker.submitCloudletList(cloudletList);

            // Sixth step: Starts the simulation
            CloudSim.startSimulation();

            CloudSim.stopSimulation();

            //Final step: Print results when simulation is over
            List<Cloudlet> newList = broker.getCloudletReceivedList();
            printCloudletList(newList);

            Log.printLine("CloudSimExample1 finished!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.printLine("Unwanted errors happen");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the datacenter.
     *
     * @param name the name
     *
     * @return the datacenter
     */
    private static Datacenter createDatacenter(String name) {

        // Here are the steps needed to create a PowerDatacenter:
        // 1. We need to create a list to store
        // our machine
        List<Host> hostList = new ArrayList<Host>();

        // 2. A Machine contains one or more PEs or CPUs/Cores.
        // In this example, it will have only one core.
        List<Pe> peList = new ArrayList<Pe>();

        int mips = 1000;

        // 3. Create PEs and add these into a list.
        peList.add(new Pe(0, new PeProvisionerSimple(mips))); // need to store Pe id and MIPS Rating

        // 4. Create Host with its id and list of PEs and add them to the list
        // of machines
        int hostId = 0;
        int ram = 2048; // host memory (MB)
        long storage = 1000000; // host storage
        int bw = 10000;

        hostList.add(
                new Host(
                        hostId,
                        new RamProvisionerSimple(ram),
                        new BwProvisionerSimple(bw),
                        storage,
                        peList,
                        new VmSchedulerTimeShared(peList)
                )
        ); // This is our machine

        // 5. Create a DatacenterCharacteristics object that stores the
        // properties of a data center: architecture, OS, list of
        // Machines, allocation policy: time- or space-shared, time zone
        // and its price (G$/Pe time unit).
        String arch = "x86"; // system architecture
        String os = "Windows"; // operating system
        String vmm = "Xen";
        double time_zone = 10.0; // time zone this resource located
        double cost = 3.0; // the cost of using processing in this resource
        double costPerMem = 0.05; // the cost of using memory in this resource
        double costPerStorage = 0.001; // the cost of using storage in this
        // resource
        double costPerBw = 0.0; // the cost of using bw in this resource
        LinkedList<Storage> storageList = new LinkedList<Storage>(); // we are not adding SAN
        // devices by now

        DatacenterCharacteristics characteristics = new DatacenterCharacteristics(
                arch, os, vmm, hostList, time_zone, cost, costPerMem,
                costPerStorage, costPerBw);

        // 6. Finally, we need to create a PowerDatacenter object.
        Datacenter datacenter = null;
        try {
            datacenter = new Datacenter(name, characteristics, new VmAllocationPolicySimple(hostList), storageList, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return datacenter;
    }

    // We strongly encourage users to develop their own broker policies, to
    // submit vms and cloudlets according
    // to the specific rules of the simulated scenario
    /**
     * Creates the broker.
     *
     * @return the datacenter broker
     */
    private static DatacenterBroker createBroker() {
        DatacenterBroker broker = null;
        try {
            broker = new DatacenterBroker("Broker");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return broker;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the Cloudlet objects.
     *
     * @param list list of Cloudlets
     */
    private static void printCloudletList(List<Cloudlet> list) {
        int size = list.size();
        Cloudlet cloudlet;

        String indent = "    ";
        Log.printLine();
        Log.printLine("========== OUTPUT ==========");
        Log.printLine("Cloudlet ID" + indent + "STATUS" + indent
                + "Data center ID" + indent + "VM ID" + indent + "Time" + indent
                + "Start Time" + indent + "Finish Time");

        DecimalFormat dft = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cloudlet = list.get(i);
            Log.print(indent + cloudlet.getCloudletId() + indent + indent);

            if (cloudlet.getCloudletStatus() == Cloudlet.SUCCESS) {
                Log.print("SUCCESS");

                Log.printLine(indent + indent + cloudlet.getResourceId()
                        + indent + indent + indent + cloudlet.getVmId()
                        + indent + indent
                        + dft.format(cloudlet.getActualCPUTime()) + indent
                        + indent + dft.format(cloudlet.getExecStartTime())
                        + indent + indent
                        + dft.format(cloudlet.getFinishTime()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error of

> [VmScheduler.vmCreate] Allocation of VM #4 to Host #0 failed by MIPS
> [VmScheduler.vmCreate] Allocation of VM #4 to Host #0 failed by MIPS